# Speech recognition using .NET Frameworks as a web service

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, web-services

If I want to build a web application to be used as a service for speech recognition. Simply, I want to transfer a speech to my website to be recognized and then get the speech as a text.

What is the best way to implement this application to run on a ASP.NET website?

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is run a WCF service on your server to do the Speech recognition using Microsoft Speech Recognition API (SAPI) and let your web service to talk with your WCF Service . Basically, the web service needs to get the audio, stream it and send it to the WCF service.

YOu can find more information on this post:
http://blog.renzuocheng.com/2011/03/speech-recognitionsapi-in-asp-net2/

Comment: Does SAPI work in a multithreaded application, or is it an old ActiveX control?

Answer (score 0):

There are many parts here.

- How to read the user and send it to the server
- How to make speech recognition
- Return the result to the user

Here I answer to the first part, how to read the user input. For how to make speech recognition, I think that you need to make a research for find the correct module. One that I know is the Microsoft [.NET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Framework) Speech SDK 1 that you need to find it.

### Using HTML5

A new way is to use the `x-webkit-speech` key as:

```
<input type="text" x-webkit-speech="x-webkit-speech" />
```

You then can send this data to the server for speech recognition.

Some examples:

- Stack Overflow question *[x-webkit-speech help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5534153/x-webkit-speech-help)*
- *[How to Use HTML5 Speech Input Fields](http://www.sitepoint.com/html5-speech-input-fields/#fbid=ke9aKB6A5bN)*
- *[x-webkit-speech input and textareas](http://www.phpied.com/x-webkit-speech-input-and-textareas/)*

### Using Flash

To be able to use a speech recognition, you need to add Flash to your site to be able to read the microphone from the user computer (this is done with the permission of the user).

On your script on the Flash, you get what the user speaks and your processing on the server side.

Comment: Your answer has some kind of help but i want to add some hints. I just want to know what is the best library i should use to perform speech recognition, I don't need any help about how to to build the website, I just want to build a .NET service on my website that take my speech in some way from my mobile  or laptop to recognize it then return required text. This services would be used through a desktop app or mobile app not through the website itself.

Comment: @MAMoselhie I do not know what is the best lib to use, this is something that you need to check out by your self. On my university I remember some years ago was a project for speech recognition. This is something that there be done many times, from many universities, I do not know what is the best and what you can have to use it. Maybe you can even have it for free from google api, I do not know know... test test and test again.